# Syntax error on token ",", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, android, syntax, syntax-error

I'm getting an eclipse error stating:

```
Syntax error on token ",", Identifier expected after this token
```

on the line:

```
@Element(name="Video", =false)
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I did a google and SO search and I wasn't able to come up with much.

### Source:

```
public class Post extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.testparse);
         @Element(name="Title",required=false)
            String title;

            @Element(name="Video", =false)
            String video;

    }
    private void doParse()
    {
                // static body here, but you can pass a Stream to the serializer too
        String xmlBody = "<response><cmd>getPosts</cmd><success>1</success><NumberOfSongs>4</NumberOfSongs><Posts><Post><Title>Stream</Title><Video/></Post><Post><Title>Movies</Title><Video/></Post><Post><Title>Music</Title><Video/></Post><Post><Title>Hello world!</Title><Video/></Post></Posts></response>";

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        PostResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = serializer.read(PostResponse.class, xmlBody);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // something interesting with the classes now

    }
}
```

Comment: What's equal to false?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `required=false` like the other String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, you have a syntax error missing the key for that value:
You are writing:

```
@Element(name="Video", =false)
```

and you are missing the "required"

```
@Element(name="Title",required=false)
```